# Can visual studio express is able to run ssis packages?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ssis, ssis-2012, visual-studio-express

I have created SSIS packages using visual studio can i open it and run the same packages on visual studio express? I have installed viual studio express 2015 and SSDT 2015 installed but in my new project template it havent show the option to create new SSIS package.

Comment: Before you post, summarize the problem and provide details and example for that to describe what you’ve tried.

Comment: Before you post, summarize the problem and provide details and example for that to describe what you’ve tried.